# How to add a comment to setup.cfg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'd like to add a comment to my setup.cfg but I do not know the right syntax

## setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = mypackage
```

## pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

## mypackage/**init**.py

empty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A line beginning with # is a comment:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.0.1

# this is a comment
[options]
packages = mypackage
```

Note that the following does **not** work:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = mypackage  # this is NOT a comment
```